# Receive and Parse Emails on AWS SES

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I want to setup a Lambda function to parse incoming emails to SES. I followed the documentation and setup the receipt rules.

I tested out my script by storing a MIME email in a txt file, parsing the email, and storing required info in a JSON document to be stored in a database. Now, I'm unsure of how to access the received email from SES and pull the information into my Python script. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from email.parser import Parser
parser = Parser()

f = open('roundtripMime.txt', "r")
rawText = f.read()
incoming = Parser().parsestr(rawText)

subject = incoming
subjectList = subject.split("|")

#Get number
NumberList = subjectList[0].split()
Number = NumberList[2].strip("()")

#Get Name
fullNameList = subjectList[3].split("/")
firstName = fullNameList[1].strip()
lastName = fullNameList[0].strip()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set up an Action in your SES Rules Set to automatically PUT your email files into S3. Then you set up an event in S3 (for a specific bucket) to trigger your lambda function. With that, you will be able to retrieve the email with something like this:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    for record in event['Records']:
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name'] 
        # here you can download the file from s3 with bucket and key
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that joarleymoraes suggested the mult-part solution you are looking for. I'll try to further elaborate on this process. First, you'll want to utilize [S3 Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-s3.html) within Simple Email Service.

1. **[SES S3 Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-s3.html)** - *PUT your email to an S3 bucket*

Second, after the *S3 Action* (within the same SES *[receipt rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-concepts.html)* as your S3 Action) schedule your S3 email processing [Lambda Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-lambda.html) trigger.

2. **[Lambda Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-lambda.html)** - *GET from S3 and process the email contents*

The [AWS SES documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-lambda-example-functions.html) shows "Lambda Function Example #4" demonstrating the steps required to obtain your email from S3:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var bucketName = '<YOUR BUCKET GOES HERE>';

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    console.log('Process email');

    var sesNotification = event.Records[0].ses;
    console.log("SES Notification:\n", JSON.stringify(sesNotification, null, 2));

    // Retrieve the email from your bucket
    s3.getObject({
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: sesNotification.mail.messageId
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
                callback(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Raw email:\n" + data.Body);

                // Custom email processing goes here

                callback(null, null);
            }
        });
};
```

Answer (score -2):

See [Amazon Simple Email Service document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email.html)

Actually, there is a better way; using [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/sqs.html#processing-messages), you can send email and process messages easily.

```
# Get the service resource
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')

# Get the queue
queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='test')

# Process messages by printing out body and optional author name
for message in queue.receive_messages(MessageAttributeNames=['Author']):
    # Get the custom author message attribute if it was set
    author_text = ''
    if message.message_attributes is not None:
        author_name = message.message_attributes.get('Author').get('StringValue')
        if author_name:
            author_text = ' ({0})'.format(author_name)

    # Print out the body and author (if set)
    print('Hello, {0}!{1}'.format(message.body, author_text))

    # Let the queue know that the message is processed
    message.delete()
```

Comment: It seems like this is receiving SQS messages (events), not SES (mail messages). What am I missing?